# Is it posssible to store selenium objects? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to catch errors in my automation program and pass them as arguments to another function.
My objective is to store these selenium objects which caused errors during automaton and handle them after main functions are finished.

For now, I am sending error details into csv file:

```
def send_keys_dropdown(self,url,csv_name):
        elements = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-tag='globalize']")
        for elem in elements:
            class_of_element = elem.get_attribute("class")
            if class_of_element == 'CsLinkButton':
                try:
                   # Some actions here
                except (ElementNotInteractableException, ElementNotVisibleException) as e:
                    handle_errors(elem, url, e)
                    pass
```

As you see, **handle_errors()** function takes 3 arguments and:

```
    def handle_errors(self, elem, url, e):
        bot = self.bot
        with open('errors.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['URL', 'Element', 'Error']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({ 'URL': url, 'Element': elem, 'Error':e })
        with open('errors.csv', 'rt',encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
            errors_list = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            errors_list = list(errors_list)
            bot.get(url)
            time.sleep(3)
```

This function will take url from csv and go the page which caused error and next should be find element which caused error. However, I don't know how to store these selenium objects.

I tried to pass element directly (without writing csv) but it's still not working.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: use element.getAttribute('innerHTML') and element.getAttribute('outerHTML')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to retry/investigate errors after your main script is finished. In that case, it's not possible to save WebElement object directly for future use because all context for the element is lost already.

You can save the locator to the csv, or, as @pcalkins suggested, save the content of HTML if you want to investigate later.

Also, I suggest that you split the part reading errors form `handle_error()` and move it to the place where you want to retry/investigate.

```
    def send_keys_dropdown(self,url,csv_name):
        by, locator = By.XPATH, "//a[@data-tag='globalize']"
        elements = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-tag='globalize']")
        for elem in elements:
            class_of_element = elem.get_attribute("class")
            if class_of_element == 'CsLinkButton':
                try:
                   # Some actions here
                except (ElementNotInteractableException, ElementNotVisibleException) as e:
                    handle_errors(by, locator, url, e)
                    pass

    def handle_errors(self, by, locator, url, e):
        bot = self.bot
        with open('errors.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['URL', 'By', 'Locator', 'Error']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({ 'URL': url, 'By': by, 'Locator': locator, 'Error':e })

    def retry_errors(self):
        bot = self.bot
        with open('errors.csv', 'rt',encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
            errors_list = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            errors_list = list(errors_list)
            for error in errors_list:
              # actions you want to retry
```

Comment: Great Solution, Thank you very much!